# How can I remove all the text within two delimiters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to ignore some text within parenthesis when parsing a textfile.  The two delimiters would be ().  Note: this is a cmd/batch question.

> a usable substring (ignore some text in parenthesis)

> (ignore some text in parenthesis) a usable substring

> (ignore some text in parenthesis) another usable substring (ignore more text in parenthesis)

> (ignore this line completely)

I tried:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (type test.txt) do set string=%%a
set var=!string:(*)=!
echo: !var!
```

Couldn't get that lucky, of course.

`for /f "delims=()" %%a in (%string%) do` worked for some, but not all, of the test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is based on split each line using quotes as delimiters for the parts, so the method fails if the file contains quotes.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   call :ignoreText
   if defined line echo !line!
)
goto :EOF

:ignoreText
set "line= %line:)=" ^& set "line=^!line^!%"
set "line=%line:(=" & set "omit=%"
set "line=%line:~1%"
exit /B
```

The method split the line at each `(` and `)` in different behavior. In summary, it converts a line like this:

```
take one (omit one) take two
```

... in this line that is *executed*:

```
set "line=take one " & set "omit=omit one" & set "line=!line! take two"
```

You can appreciate this behavior more clearly if you remove the `@echo off` command and carefully review the executed code.

Comment: Although Magoo's solution also works for the test that I gave, it will fail if there are touching sets of parenthesis (x)(no whitespace)(x) so I consider this one to be better for my needs. I shouldn't ever encounter double quotes.  Also both solutions fail if there are nested parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75560170.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "line= %%e"&CALL :deparen

GOTO :EOF

:deparen
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=()" %%u IN ("%line%") DO IF "%%v" neq "" SET "line=%%u%%w"&GOTO deparen
ECHO/%line:~1%
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that a space is prepended to the line in order that `(` is never the first character.

The final `echo/` does not misbehave if `%line:~1%` is empty

(I'm assuming that each line may contain balanced parenthesis-pairs)